# How to upload bigger files (200mb+) to blob storage using react and node js (server side)? without saving file on server

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, large-file-upload

Earlier we were using aws multipart upload. so approach was simple and straightforward. i have to call three apis from my react frontend.multipart upload/chunk url/complete upload.
found this great [tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6VHc41idHZs&t=9014s).

I want to upload a large file to azure, not able to find straight forward answer or tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to upload the file to blob storage programmatically then we can do this by dividing the file in chunks and each chunk will have an id and we upload the chunks separately.
- Here we upload each chunk of data with an id and we also store the id in an list and we upload the list itself too.

Refer the following [article](https://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/) by Gavrav Mantri

Comment: The code in my blog post made use of REST API directly because at that time JavaScript SDK was not available. I would actually recommend making use of SDK now.